# Unknown tag tiles:insertAttribute

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, struts2, tiles

I'm trying to use Tiles to show a `div` in JSP page, but Eclipse shows me a warning like this:

```
Unknown tag (tiles:insertAttribute)
```

**This is my `index.jsp`:**

```jsp
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">     
    <tiles:insertAttribute name="header" />
</nav>
<!--  Main container  -->
<div class="container-fluid text-center">
    <div class="row content">
<!-- Right menu -->     
        <div class="col-sm-2 sidenav">
            <tiles:insertAttribute name="menu" />
        </div>
```

**This is my `tiles.xml`:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<!DOCTYPE tiles-definitions PUBLIC
   "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Tiles Configuration 2.0//EN"
   "http://tiles.apache.org/dtds/tiles-config_2_0.dtd">
<tiles-definitions>
    <definition name="index" template="/index.jsp">
        <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
        <put-attribute name="header" value="/Header.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="menu" value="/Menu.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="body" value="/Body.jsp" />
        <put-attribute name="footer" value="/Footer.jsp" />
    </definition>
```

**And this in my `web.xml`:**

```xml
<listener>
    <listener- class>org.apache.struts2.tiles.StrutsTilesListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<context-param>
    <param-name>tilesDefinitions</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

---

**EDIT:**

This is part of my `pom.xml`, if need more info, please ask me.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.cice.adelagd</groupId>
<artifactId>proyectoNUS</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>proyectoNUS Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.25</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.geronimo.specs</groupId>
        <artifactId>geronimo-jta_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.1-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jandex</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.22.0-GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
        <artifactId>antlr</artifactId>
        <version>3.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.14.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>proyectoNUS</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
            <configuration>
                <webApp>
                    <contextPath>/${project.build.finalName}</contextPath>
                </webApp>
                <stopKey>CTRL+C</stopKey>
                <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
                <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                <scanTargets>
                    <scanTarget>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</scanTarget>
                </scanTargets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a taglib directive for tiles in your JSP files?

Comment: What is the version of tiles?

Comment: May be this? I'm sorry but I'm greed in Java..

Comment: What Is this? I don't see the version. If you don't understand java so why you asking this?

Comment: I added the pom.xml when you asked me. The version ir 2.0.6

Comment: @adelagd the pom.xml useless unless you update the version of struts2. Edit the question and update it.

Comment: @RomanC I don't Understand.. (my English is horrible, sorry). I'm working with Strust2, it's in the pom.xml.. I need another version for this dependency???

Comment: Another version won't help you untill you understand the current version and have learned English.

Comment: ok.. finally I'm not going to use it.. thanks for all

Answer (score 0):

You misunderstood the files used by the project. The `index.jsp` should not contain any menu content. It's should be better named `head` or `menu` tile.

To use `tiles:` prefix to tags in JSP you should define a taglib :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="tiles" uri="http://tiles.apache.org/tags-tiles" %>
```

Comment: Don't use it in index.jsp

Comment: I don't know what you see but you should rename the file index.jsp to something else because index.jsp is a special file name used to show a directory contents.